# how to proceed once a file containing something in shell

Tags: bash

I am writing some BASH shell script that will continuously check a file to see if the file already contains "Completed!" before proceeding. (Of course, assume the file is being updated and will eventually contain the phrase "Completed!")

I am not sure how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
while ! grep -q -e 'Completed!' file ; do
  sleep 1 # Or some other number of seconds
done

# Here the file contains completed
```

Comment: And if you want the match on Completed to be case-insensitive you can add -i after grep.

Answer (score 1):

Amongst the standard utilities, [`tail`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tail.html) has an option to keep reading from a file: `tail -f`. So filter the output of `tail -f`.

```
<some_file tail -f -n +1 | grep 'Completed!' | head -n 1 >/dev/null
```

There may be a delay due to buffering. You can at least reduce the delay by using fewer tools in the pipeline. In fact, some implementations of `tail` never buffer when you do `tail -f`, so the following snippet will return as soon as `Completed!` is written to the file.

```
<some_file tail -f -n +1 | sed -e '/Completed!/ q'
```

This assumes that the file is being appended to by some other tool. If the file is *overwritten* by the data-producing program after you start `tail`, this solution won't work. You can [search the file periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245646/how-to-proceed-once-a-file-containing-something-in-shell/6245678#6245678). On some systems you can call a notification mechanism to know whenever the file changes, e.g. with [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in Kornshell:

```
tail -f somefile | while read line
do
    echo $line
    [[ $line == *Completed!* ]] && break
done
```

Note no quotes around the **Completed!** string. This allows the double square brackets to do glob pattern matching instead of string matching.

This seems to work in BASH too. However, the line with the `Completed` must end in a NL. Otherwise, it'll take an extra line before it breaks the loop.

You can use `grep` too:

```
tail -f somefile | while read line
do
    echo $line
    grep -iq "Completed!" && break
done
```

The `-q` parameter means quiet. If your `grep` doesn't take the `-q` parameter, you might have to pipe it to `/dev/null`. The `-i` is ignore case. Whether you want to do that is up to you.

The advantage is that you aren't doing any processing unless there's a line to read. Using `sleep` may mean you miss the line, or that you're processing when no line has been added to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` in a pipe you may turn on line buffering mode by adding the `--line-buffered` option!